# Java: Get all Strings using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get all the strings from a javascript script, I created a code, but it's not catching all, it's skipping some

***My Code***

```java
String Strings;
    public String GetStrings(String str){
        try{
        String Str= str;
         Strings = "";
         while(true){
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("('|\")");    
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Str);    
            if(matcher.find()){
                Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(" + matcher.group(1) + "[^" + matcher.group(1) + "]*" + matcher.group(1) + ")");    
                Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(Str);    
                if(matcher1.find()){
                    Strings += "|" + matcher1.group(1) + "|";
                    Str =  Str.replace(matcher1.group(1)," ");
                }
                }else{
                    break;
                    }
        }
        }catch(Exception err){return err.toString(); }
        return Strings;
        }
```

***Input***

```js
var A="&";var B="(";var D="[]";var X="'";var W='&';var Q='';var STR="'";var Q="'******'";var G="^";var F="...";var T='$';var wm = "()"
console.log(A + B + D + "^" + wm + '#');
```

***Output***

```java
|"&"||"("||"[]"||"'"||'&'||''||"'******'"||"^"||"..."||'$'||"()"||'#'|
```

As you can see not captured all the strings, some did not appear, if anyone has any solution or can point the problem, please help me

Comment: You really need a _parser_ to handle this requirement in the general case.  By the way, many here would opine that having a lot of hard-coded string literals in a JavaScript (or, really any language), is bad practice.  Instead, consider maintaining a constants file with definitions for your string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use following regex:

```
(\"(.*?)\")|(\'(.*?)\')
```

example:

```
public String getStrings(String str){
   String regex = "(\\\"(.*?)\\\")|(\\'(.*?)\\')";

   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

   String output = "";
   while (matcher.find()){
       output = output+"|"+matcher.group(0)+"|";
   }

   return output;

}
```

Output:

```
|"&"||"("||"[]"||"'"||'&'||''||"'"||"'******'"||"^"||"..."||'$'||"()"||"^"||'#'|
```

> **[Regex Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/dxX48B/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Input and expected output is not matching but according what i understood is

```
public String GetStrings(String str){    
       StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
       for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {

            char ch = str.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isWhitespace(ch))
                b.append("\\s");
            else if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                b.append("\\d");
            else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
                b.append("A-Z");
            else if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))
                b.append("a-z");
        }
                b.append("||");

        }
```